# Getting the results of the row when using Sequel table_name.all

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

I'm trying to retrieve all the rows of my table using Sequel with the following:

```
puts MyApp::Model::SystemStatus.all
```

When I print this out in my console, I get the following:

```
#<MyApp::Model::SystemStatus:0x6ac154ff>
#<MyApp::Model::SystemStatus:0x63d4d172>
#<MyApp::Model::SystemStatus:0x46d7f284>
```

My question is - how do I get it to print out all information from each column instead of just a hash of the row?

For example, each `SystemStatus` row has the following columns:

`| id | is_valid | message | created_date |`

Comment: Just MyApp::Model::SystemStatus.all will give you all the records in such table, or by using `p`, but not `puts`. Also if you want just to select some attribute then you can use select: `MyApp::Model::SystemStatus.select(:id, :is_valid, :message, :created_date)`.

Comment: `p` worked - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print all the attribute when using all over a model, then `puts` must be used together `inspect`:

```
puts MyApp::Model::SystemStatus.all.inspect
```

Or using `p`, or just leaving the console returns you what MyApp::Model::SystemStatus.all contains.

Also if you want just to select some attribute then you can use select:

```
MyApp::Model::SystemStatus.select(:id, :is_valid, :message, :created_date)
```